# Populate a Matrix based on user input and a pattern in C

Tags: c, string, matrix, populate

I have a program to develop but I'm having some difficulties in one part.
I have to read a number of tests (`t`) that will be made. After that I must read a number (`n`) of columns and rows to make a square matrix² (nxn). After instance of the matrix, the program must populate it from the input of the user. The user will type `.`, `b` or `w`. Based in this pattern I have to populate the matrix. Each line that the user will type must contain `n` characters (`.`, `b` or `w`) and he will type n times. This will fill the matrix (n characters by n lines). Can you guys give me a hand?

This is the code I have:

```
int main(void)
{
    //vars
    int n = 0, t = 1, x = -1, y = -1, teste = 1;
    int i,j;
    //Start
    scanf(" %d %*c",&t);//scans t
    while (t-- > 0) {
        scanf(" %d", &n);//scans n
        if(n>0 && n < 100){
            int table[n][n];//the matrix n x n
            for (i = 0; (i < n);++i) {//iterator to lines
                char l[n];
                scanf ("%s", l); //scans a line
                for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {//iterator to colums
        //these ifs are to identfy the input
                   if (l[j] == 'b'){
                        table[i][j]=1;
                    }else if(l[j] == 'w'){
                        table[i][j]=2;
                        x=j;y=i;
                    }else{
                        table[i][j]=0;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I made the exactly same thing in Java and it worked. Where am I failing?

Comment: Can you explain that first scanf?

Comment: @RogerRowland Its scanning a counter, followed by a throw-away char that is parsed but not stored in any out-parameter. (not sure if that was the kind of explanation you were looking for).

Comment: You realize with each iteration of the outer-while-loop the prior matrix is completely lost due to scope reset of the while-loop, correct ? Also, while cutting out what may be highly relevant code, you left out the closing brace of the `for (i` loop.

Comment: Ok thanks, wasn't sure if a missing out parameter is a problem.

Comment: what problem you facing, what is the error/issues in this?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `l` doesn't allow enough space to store the null at the end of the string.  You are therefore overflowing into some other variable, and that may be affecting all sorts of things.

You should probably read the line into a far larger string, and make sure it is the correct length.  You should also error check each read operation; you should also report invalid characters in the input.

This code works for me.  Note the way it echoes data so it is possible to see what's going wrong.  Error reporting should really be to standard error; I've been lazy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void dump_board(FILE *fp, const char *tag, int n, int table[n][n])
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s: (%d x %d)\n", tag, n, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (table[i][j] == 0)
                putc('=', fp);
            else if (table[i][j] == 1)
                putc('B', fp);
            else if (table[i][j] == 2)
                putc('W', fp);
            else
                putc('?', fp);
        }
        putc('\n', fp);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 0, t = 1, x = -1, y = -1;

    if (scanf(" %d %*c", &t) != 1)
    {
        printf("Failed to read t\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d data sets\n", t);

    while (t-- > 0)
    {
        if (scanf(" %d", &n) != 1)
        {
            printf("Failed to read n\n");
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Size of data set: %d x %d\n", n, n);
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            ;

        if (n > 0 && n < 100)
        {
            int table[n][n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                char line[4096];
                if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == 0)
                    break;
                int len = strlen(line);
                if (line[len-1] != '\n')
                {
                    printf("Format error: line too long (%d bytes)\n", len);
                    return 1;
                }
                line[--len] = '\0';
                if (len != n)
                {
                    printf("Format error: line <<%s>> is not length %d\n", line, n);
                    return 1;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                {
                    if (line[j] == 'b')
                        table[i][j] = 1;
                    else if (line[j] == 'w')
                    {
                        table[i][j] = 2;
                        x = j;
                        y = i;
                    }
                    else if (line[j] == '.')
                        table[i][j] = 0;
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Format error: invalid character %c\n", line[j]);
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            dump_board(stdout, "Input", n, table);
            printf("Last white piece at (%d,%d)\n", x, y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Input

```
2x
4
b..w
.bw.
.b.b
w.w.
8
b.w.b.w.
.w.b.w.b
bbwwbbww
b......w
ww....bb
bwb..wbw
bbbbwwww
........
```

#### Output

```
2 data sets
Size of data set: 4 x 4
Input: (4 x 4)
B==W
=BW=
=B=B
W=W=
Last white piece at (2,3)
Size of data set: 8 x 8
Input: (8 x 8)
B=W=B=W=
=W=B=W=B
BBWWBBWW
B======W
WW====BB
BWB==WBW
BBBBWWWW
========
Last white piece at (7,6)
```

Comment: When i try your main standalone it fails in the scan of n :/

Comment: i mean i would like to overwrite your dumbtable function and put mine. it will consume the table in a recoursive loop and all. But my problem is in generate this table.. your code is in c99 i suspect.. can it be the reason to not work here? (devc++5.0.0.9 or ideone.com). I'd like to tanks your answer and your effort ^^ tks.

Comment: Yes, my code is C99, but since you are using VLAs, your code must be C99 too.  If you are having problems with the scan of `n`, the chances are that you've got some odd data for your `%*c` format specifier to read.  The `x` in my data file is not there by accident; it satisfies your slightly unusual conversion specifier.

Comment: It worked but the problem is that it won't read the imput of the judge.. it stops in 8bits (char read) there's a way to make it read a any value string?

Comment: There's a way to do whatever you're trying to do. I've no idea what you mean by the 'input of the judge', nor by 'it stops in 8-bits (char read)'. If the latter means "it won't read a character with the high bit (8th bit) set", then you're going to have to do some explaining about why the data needs such characters (the problem specification doesn't seem to need it), and show the minimal code (and data file) that exhibits the problem you're seeing (because most modern systems handle all 256 byte codes fine). Are you using UTF-8 as your data encoding by any chance?  Please update the question.